# Clearing the search context manually after reindexing is done

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We have a shell script which takes the name of an index and then reindexes it.
We are using ES 7.17.0
The reindex command-

```
response=$(curl -u $CREDENTIALS -X POST "$PROTOCOL://$HOST:9200/_reindex?slices=50&refresh&wait_for_completion=false" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"source\": { \"index\": \"$INDEX\",\"size\":5}, \"dest\": { \"index\": \"$new_index\" } }" --write-out '%{http_code}')
```

Here we are using slice and size as well.But i was getting the search context missing exception and es was complaining that no search context is found for most of the slices.
The index is big and has a lot of docs.I figured out that search context expires in 5 min.Hence i am giving scroll=1h in the reindex call

But there are many indices for which it might take even more time.So instead of hardcoding it everytime i was thinking of giving it as scroll=2d
I guess this might slow down the performance of Elasticsearch as if the reindexing is completed soon,still search context will be active..

I am thinking of using the following approach-
Make scroll=2d and then if the reindexing is complete anytime sooner than clear the search context using this api-

```
DELETE /_search/scroll
 {
   "scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ=="
 }
```

Will this approach work and is this the correct approach?
I am a bit skeptical because till now we have not been touching the search context explicitly and i want to make sure clearing this doesn't lead to any other error..
Also should i use slice as auto instead of a manual number?
Any other approach to solve this issue is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using smaller batches (in `source.size`)? Maybe the default of 1000 docs per batch is too high for your environment and that's what makes each batch go over the timeout.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. 5 is really small and you'd need plenty of iterations to scroll the full index... you should probably increase it 100 or 500 maybe. You need to test

Comment: The source.size that i have given in the request is 5.Also ES would optimise it as well right?For example I have 7939 docs in my index..I had given size as 5.But in the reindexing response i see the number of batches as 397

So 7939/397 = 19 roughly..So ES optimised it.

Comment: Ok i will try to test with 100 or 500 once..Thanks for that!
Just a couple of things i want to ask
1)The optimum number for size can only be achieved by trial and error only right?Or we have any generalised formula.I couldn't find one
2)Any Advice on the second part of  the question regarding search context

Comment: Yes, trial and error because that really depends on many factors that pertain your your environment and cluster sizing only

Comment: Regarding the second part, I would touch the search context as you shouldn't have to worry about it when reindexing. You should preferably tune the reindexing with the right parameters so as to not get any search context issues

Comment: Ok Thanks alot.

Comment: Quick precision, my above sentence should have been "I would NOT touch the search context..."

Comment: haha...yes i understood that